# Как навесить событие?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Такая проблема: нужно после того, как объект создан (неизвестно когда), совершить событие click. Проблема в том, что

```
$('#id').live('load', function () {
    alert(5);
});
```

- не работает. `ready` не имеет смысла использовать. Есть какой-то способ?

Comment: `delegate`

Comment: [after][1]


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли. Нужно не вставить что-то, а совершить событие после появление элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#parentid").on("click", "#id", function(){
  alert('ok');
});
```

Вместо `#parentid` может быть document или любой другой родитель.
Пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/RGvKJ/).

Comment: не совсем понял задание, могу ошибаться...

Comment: Вот есть блок с id #id1. В нем есть кнопка $but1. Нужно нажать эту кнопку ($but1.click()), когда #id1 создан. 
Ваш пример отчасти близок. Но нужно после создания, а не клика. С этим и проблема.

Comment: Спасибо. Но решение не нужно, проблема в другом. Спасибо за помощь